# Sort Gmail inbox messages by label

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I use labels extensively in my Gmail inbox. Is there any way to sort by label? Seems like that could be quite useful.

Comment: Gmail **only** sorts by date descending.

Answer (score 4):

Impossible via the Web UI, and difficult with IMAP (coding).

[image: gmail imap layout]

Label are considered like folder on the first level of the IMAP (blured on the picture).

Messages can have several labels, some don't have any.

Sorting Email per label would required to browse the "All Mail" to create a list of all the emails, browse every single label folder to obtain the list of emails. And then process the data to sort per label. And all that via IMAP.

I'm not even thinking about how to sort emails with several labels.

It's too much effort for a poor result.

Comment: The web UI is where I'd like to do it; I'm not using IMAP.  I can *search* by label ("Label:label-name") so I guess what I need is a way to search by *all* labels, then do an "order by" kind of thing.

Comment: @user249493 the web UI sits on top of the Folder design illustrated on the answer. ("Label:label-name") means search in the folder "label-name". The same emails will be included in All mail but without any mention to the label "label-name". Label simply don't exist at the IMAP level.

Comment: @user249493 plus there's no operator for sorting email in any order http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190

Comment: +1 for "I'm not even thinking about how to sort emails with several labels. It's too much effort for a poor result."

Comment: @mhoran_psprep thanks, I really think it's possible because I'am doing things very similar with (PHP / PHP IMAP / MySQL to cache) but it's more a stackoverflow topic.

Comment: I've been using Gmail since 2004, when you had to "know someone" to get invited in.  I quickly changed my mindset from Outlook's folders to Gmail's "virtual folders" via labels.  I archive everything and rely on labels and searching to find stuff.  Despite the newer "priority inbox" feature, it seems like overall inbox functionality is stuck in the last decade.  I bet a bunch of people would find a "sort by label" very useful.